updateOne with whole struct but skip some fields
First things first. :) Programming language is Go and database is mongodb.
I have struct like this one:
type Person struct {
    ID primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id" json:"id,omitempty"`
    Name string
    LastName string
    Age int
    Address string
    City string
    FieldX string
    FieldY string
    // ...
}

In mongo there is unique index on Name, LastName and Address.
I do "initial" write to mongodb only those 3 indexed values to "lock" the record because I get some duplicates from kafka and to prevent further propagation of those.
Next I process this record and finally update mongodb document with new value. The problem is that we use some kind of sessions when working with mongo and I don't get _id of the document when it is initially inserted.
The main issue here is that I need 3 DB operations to do process one proper record.
Case #1

initial insertOne with those 3 indexed fileds (if document already exists in collection I get error and stop further processing of current record)
Since final person.ID of record after it has been processed is different from the first one I need to find _id of it in mongodb
2a) person.ID = _id found above
updateOne with _id found in #2 and whole Person struct bson.D{{"$set", person}

In case #2 I can limit no of opperations on DB to 2:

initial insertOne with those 3 indexed fields (if document already exists in collection I get error and stop further processing of current record)


updateOne with filter = indexedFields and "$set": bson.D{
                {"age", person.Age},
                {"city", person.City},
                {"fieldX", person.FieldX},
                // ...
            },

so basically listing all fields except _id and indexed fields.
It there any middle-ground solution allowing me to update document with whole person struct but without touching _id? My guess is not. ;)
BTW sorry for my poor English.
